# Convergence and value of a binomial series

Tags: taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

I wanted to know whether I am allowed to write:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} a^{-n} = (1+a^{-1})^{2n}, \ \mathrm{for} \ n > 4?
\end{equation}

I was wondering whether the exponent ($2n$ in this case) must be independent of the index of the series (i.e. $n$). Thanks.

---

Comment: I was merely wandering whether this was a trivial Taylor series, but since both sides are functions of $n$ that doesn't seem to be the case..

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment. If you change $a$ by $\frac 1x$, it is just a  normal Taylor series (the rhs cannot contain $n$). Cheers.

Comment: Take a good look at $\binom{-1/2}{k}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you I've managed to solve it. Is this a general property of some kind?

Comment: Hmm, there's of course the general principle of recognising stuff (that comes with experience, the more things you've seen the more you recognise when you see them again). As for the relations between binomial coefficients, the case $\binom{-1/2}{k}$ and the cases $\binom{-m}{k},\: m \in \mathbb{N}$ are special. Nothing that nice for e.g. $\binom{-1/3}{k}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct identity is
$$ \forall|a|<\frac{1}{4},\qquad\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}a^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4a}} $$
and it can be proved through the extended binomial theorem or the fact that
$$ \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)^{2n}\,dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

No, your equation cannot be correct, because the LHS is a summation over the index variable $n$; thus the RHS cannot be a function of $n$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. In this case, would you know how to find the value of this series ? I'm merely looking for a hint.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \equiv
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}x^{n}:\ ?\,,\qquad\mrm{f}\pars{0} = 1\,,
> \qquad \verts{x} < {1 \over 4}}$.

\begin{align}
\mrm{f}'\pars{x} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{2n}! \over n!\pars{n - 1}!}x^{n - 1} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{2n + 2}! \over \pars{n + 1}!\, n!}x^{n} =
2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{2n + 1}{\pars{2n}! \over n!\, n!}x^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
4x\,\totald{}{x}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}\,x^{n} +
2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}\,x^{n} =
4x\,\mrm{f}'\pars{x} + 2\mrm{f}\pars{x}
\\[5mm] & \implies
\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\mrm{f}'\pars{x} +
{2 \over 4x - 1}\,\mrm{f}\pars{x} = 0}
\end{align}
This differential equation can be rewritten as
$\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}\ \verts{x} < 1/4~}}$
$$
\totald{\bracks{\root{1 - 4x}\,\mrm{f}\pars{x}}}{x} = 0 \implies
\root{1 - 4x}\,\mrm{f}\pars{x} =
\root{1 - 4 \times 0}\
\overbrace{\,\mrm{f}\pars{0}}^{\ds{=\ 1}} = 1
$$

---

$$
\mrm{f}\pars{x} \equiv
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}x^{n} =
\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{1 \over \root{1 - 4x}}\,,
\qquad\verts{x} < {1 \over 4}}
$$

---

$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}a^{-n} =
\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\root{a \over a - 4}\,,
\qquad\verts{a} > 4}
$$